# How when entered a number is entered the date is displayed?

Tags: javascript, forms, switch-statement

javascript, when a number is entered eg. 1 being Monday the message received is "It's Monday".
I am using a switch statement for this.

The code I am using is:

```
function DayOfTheWeek
{
var day='1';
switch (day)
{
case '1';
 alert ("It\'s Monday");
 break;
case '2';
 alert ("Its\s Tuesday");
 break;

case '3';
 alert (It\'s Wednesday");
 break;

default:
 alert("Not a valid day");
 break;
}
```

Below is the input form code:

```
<form name="form3" method="GET" action= "parse.php">
<input type="number" name="textEntry3" />
<input type="button" value="Click me 3" onclick="DayOfTheWeek(textEntry3.value);"\>
</form>
```

I cannot seem to get this working at all
Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The syntax highlighting would tell you about a missing quote or two.  That might be the reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

I would encourage you to show your effort in resolving the matter for yourself first. However, as you are new, try the following.

The function you have defined takes no argument. You are statically assigning `1` to your variable. Define a parameter for your function and use it in the switch statement. See [W3C School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) for a tutorial on Javascript functions.

You might also want to read the site's guidelines on how to ask questions!

Comment: Thanks, I realised after posting the question it made no sense!